# Transparent PNG in a div tag, not using alpha?

Tags: html, css, png, transparency, alpha

I have an odd issue while beginning to learn CSS. [This](http://www.blindmanstudio.com/test2/) is a test page. It has a large transparent PNG covering the background color of solid blue.

Typically the black image (which has transparent holes in it) completely blacks out my background color.

In this example page I made the image's div transparent just to see if the background was still working.

Any ideas why my alpha is getting completely ignored?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

It's because on `.backgrounddiv` you have `background-color` set to `#000`. Instead use `transparent` to fix:

```
.backgrounddiv {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image:url(POCTransparentBG.png);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.backgrounddiv {
    position:absolute;
    background: transparent url('POCTransparentBG.png');
}
```

this is the proper css.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at your page, and it seems like the div with the background image on it (backgrounddiv) is styled to also have a solid black background (#000). If you remove the:

```
background-color: #000;
```

From your source, it looks the way you'd like!