# transparent png not rendering as transparent?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I saved the image as a transparent png but nothing I can do seems to fix it!?!  Any ideas???

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Here is a copy of the image in GIMP showing that it's indeed transparent:

[image]

finally, Some good old code:

The Markup:

```
<form class="search" action="search.php"><input class="search" type="text" name="search" id="searchbox"/></form>
```

Search Box CSS:

```
.search, .search:active, .search:focus, .search:visited {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    top: 3px;
    width: 368px;
    right: 9%;
    font-size: 28px;
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: 20px;
    /* box-shadow: inset -2px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.8); */
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-shadow: 0px -2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    background-color: #00D4C7;
}
```

The Search icon css itself:

```
Pseudo ::before element
.search:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 7px;
    left: 268px;
    background-image: url("images/icon-search.png");
    background-color: rgb(0, 185, 171);
    width: 46px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

**Note:**  If I remove the class search from form, It removes my image, if I remove class search from the input element it still renders with that funky shade over my image...Any ideas?

**Edit 1:**  If I do as suggested by setting the explicit dimensions of the image (as I did for other pseudo elements with no problem) it does not resolve my issue.  I've already submitted the project so at this point it's a matter of me wanting to know what happened and how I can fix this.  I resorted to a css hack that changed the brightness to a closer match [with a faint outline still  ]

[image]

**Edit 2:** Show me the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g490vove/1/)!

Comment: Be sure to check your css as well. You have applied the "search" class to both the form and input element.

Answer (score 2):

My image itself was not truly transparent.  There is is a small opacity channel that causes that grey haze to appear on a non-white background. I caught wind of this when posting to imgur....and confirmed it for sure when I actually made a copy of the layer (in photoshop) using `select by color`.

[image]

**Solution:**  Check your images...to do this, load it onto a window by itself and set the html body to a non-white color.  Wish I thought to do this before submitting this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you did give your image a `background-color: rgb(0, 185, 171);` what is #00b9ab

and the searchbox   `background-color: #00D4C7;`   what is   rgb(0, 212, 199)

Comment: I tried to set the element as transparent as per this answer without resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165704/2226328

Comment: and if you give him the same background color?

Comment: it is the first time I see something like that so I just guessing now  but did you try to put the image in the div as a image not as background-image?

Comment: No it was just as a pseudo element that sits after...I suppose I can try to give it relative positioning with a z-index higher than the box but lower than the text itself and see if doing it that way fixes it – And it doesn't resolve anything, even storing this as a generic separate image with inline styling to set the background color - its like there is a weird overlay on this specific image...I'm at a loss for explanation

Answer (score 1):

I found that the images that I was getting from the internet were not truly transparent. This website enabled me to get it to work. https://www.remove.bg/ (the image I used had the checkered background to indicate it was transparent, it just didn't work in the img tag until I used that website.)

Comment: telling someone to use a website as a 'solution' to fix an issue is typically a terrible idea, 99% of the time. in 2022 you can use paint3d which is built in on windows to set an alpha channel for a given color to make it transparent.

Comment: I respect your opinion. Some folks like myself don't need to put something into production. Something quick will do. Your solution didn't help me do that quickly. Powerpoint didn't work either for me even though it did remove the background it still didn't work when I linked in it my html. I rather share and it help someone like me than not because another person may disagree. To each their own

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because your background image size is different than its container's, `.search::before`, size. And/or because your `.search::before` background-color is a different hex value.

Try this:
Add `background-color: transparent;` and `background-size: 46px 30px;` to `.search::before`. This will make it so that if your background image is smaller than the container, the rest of the space will be transparent and set the background image size to be the same as its container, which you have explicitly set.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but didn't see improvement

Comment: Hmm..any chance you could place your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Your image isn't coming through to the fiddle, do you have a working link?

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe the problem all along is with your image? I get the following error when trying to view your image url: 'The image "http://puu.sh/oorCR/5df782036a.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.' Got another image, perhaps open-source, that we could try to determine if bug is CSS or image related?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/RNJe5EV.png  interesting that I see the overlay on black text when looking on imgur too...this lead me to believe it has to do with the photo and nothing to do with my code...Yup...that's it : \ http://puu.sh/oosKv/dd2990a89d.png